# Fitting with Lmfit several datsets with shared parameters and one fixed parameter for each dataset

Tags: curve-fitting, curve, least-squares

I'm at beginner level in python and I come across a problem.
I would like to use the lmfit module to fit a function to a 3 sets of (x, y) data from .csv file, with some shared parameters (a,b,d) and one fixed individual parameters (c).
My data is in the following format:
x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..

..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..

Here is an example of a exponential function, and my attempt of fitting to each data-set and plotting. I'm having problems defining the global residual and also to define a fixed value for each data set of the c parameter. This is what I've got so far:

```
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Load data
df=pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
df[['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3','y3']][:6]

# set up the data
xs = np.array(df[df.columns[0::2]]) 
ys = np.array(df[df.columns[1::2]]) 

#define function
def biexp(xs,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.exp(-xs*b*c)+(1-a)*np.exp(-xs*d*c)
 
 #Define a function that calculates biexp for data set i
def biexp_dataset(params, i, xs):
    a = params['a_%i' % (i+1)].value
    b = params['b_%i' % (i+1)].value
    c = params['c_%i' % (i+1)].value
    d = params['d_%i' % (i+1)].value
    return biexp(xs,a,b,c,d)
    
#Define the real function to minimize, which calculates the total residual for all fits, modeled by biexp function
"""Where I'm stuck"""
def objective(params, xs,ys):
    nys, nxs= df.shape[1]/2
    resid = 0.0*ys[:]
    # make residual per data set
    for i in range(nys):
       resid = ys[:, i] - biexp_dataset(params,i,xs)
    # now flatten this to a 1D array, as minimize() needs
    return resid.flatten()

#Define parameters
fit_params = Parameters()
for i in range(df.shape[1]/2): 
    fit_params.add( 'a_%i' % (i+1), value=1, min=0,  max=9,vary=True)
    fit_params.add( 'b_%i' % (i+1), value=0.3, min=0.0, vary=True)
    fit_params.add( 'd_%i' % (i+1), value=0.5, min=0.0,  vary=True)
"""How can I define c for each data sets?"""
"""Iwant for x1,y1 => c1=2; x2,y2=>c2=0.4; x3,y3=>c3=5, for example"""

#  constrain all values of a,b and d to have the same value
for i in (2, 3):
    fit_params['a_%i' % i].expr='a_1'
    fit_params['b_%i' % i].expr='b_1'
    fit_params['d_%i' % i].expr='d_1'

      
# run the global fit to all the data sets
result=minimize(objective, fit_params, args=(xs, ys))
report_fit(result.params)

# plot the data sets and fits
plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]/2):
    y_fit = biexp_dataset(fit_params, i, xs)
    plt.plot(xs[:,i], ys[:, i], 'o', xs[:,i], y_fit, '-')

plt.show()
```

So basically WhatI'm asking is: how do I define a fixed c parameter value for  each data set? c1=0.4; c2=1;c3=5, for example

What I'm doing wrong in the objective definition since when I run the code it states: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Any help would be appreciated....

Update

So I made some new code using the real function that I wanted to fit (and that I already fitted using global fit option in originLab). So, my datasets share the same D1,D2,tau1 and tau2. However the model as a new variable fixed which is experimental time (t_exps). Now I don't have any errors in the code but what I obtain is not 6 fitted curves for the six datasets but 36 curve fits. I'm lost... What is wrong with my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#set up the data
df=pd.read_excel('BTMS_hex.xlsx')

df = df.dropna() #drop rows that have invalid values (extra line in data file)
# set up the data
xs = np.array(df[df.columns[0::2]]).astype(float)
ys = np.log(np.array(df[df.columns[1::2]]).astype(float))
t_exps = [0.04857, 0.0989, 0.14923, 0.1993, 0.49957, 0.99957]


#Create function
def karger(xs,D1,D2,tau1,tau2,texp):
    term1=D1+D2+(1/(xs/texp))*((1/tau1)+(1/(tau2)))
    term2=np.sqrt(((D1-D2+(1/(xs/texp))*((1/tau1)+(1/(tau2))))**2)+(4/(((xs/texp)**2)*tau1*tau2)))
    DA=0.5*(term1-term2)
    DB=0.5*(term1+term2)
    P1=tau1/(tau1+tau2)
    P2=1-P1
    CB=(P1*D1+P2*D2-DA)/(DB-DA)
    return np.log((1-CB)*np.exp(-xs*DA)+CB*np.exp(-xs*DB))

def karger_dataset(params, xs,texp):
    D1 = params['D1'].value
    D2 = params['D2'].value
    tau1 = params['tau1'].value
    tau2 = params['tau2'].value 
    return karger(xs, D1,D2,tau1,tau2,texp)
    
def objective(params, xs,ys):
    resid = np.array([])
    for i in range(xs.shape[1]):
        y_pred = karger_dataset(params, xs[:,i],t_exps[i])
        resid=np.concatenate((resid,(ys[:, i] - y_pred)))     
    return resid

#Define parameters
fit_params = Parameters()
fit_params.add( 'D1', value=2E-1,min=0, vary=False)
fit_params.add( 'D2', value=1E-2, min=0, vary=True)
fit_params.add( 'tau1', value=8.2, min=0, vary=True)
fit_params.add( 'tau2', value=0.5, min=0,  vary=True)

# run the global fit to all the data sets
result=minimize(objective, fit_params, args=(xs, ys))
report_fit(result.params)

print result.residual

# plot the data sets and fits
plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]/2):
    y_fit = karger_dataset(fit_params, xs,t_exps[i])
    plt.plot(xs[:,i], ys[:, i], 'o', xs[:,i], y_fit, '-')

"plt.yscale('log')"
plt.axis([0,1600, -10,0.1])
plt.savefig('books_read.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

For

> So basically WhatI'm asking is: how do I define a fixed c parameter
>   value for each data set? c1=0.4; c2=1;c3=5, for example

why not just do

```
fit_params.add('c1', value=0.4, vary=False)
fit_params.add('c2', value=1.0, vary=False)
fit_params.add('c3', value=5.0, vary=False)
```

after the `for i in range(df.shape[1]/2):` loop defining your other parameters?

For

> What I'm doing wrong in the objective definition since when I run 
>   the code it states: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Without seeing the full traceback (which would probably tell you the line of code where this exception was happening) I would guess that somewhere there is a list instead of an numpy array being multiplied by a float.

I don't quite understand why you get that error instead of a "I cannot find parameter 'c1'" error, but that suggests it might be happening before you even get to running your fit.  A full traceback would clarify that.

Comment: The update is completely unrelated to the original question, and you did not even say whether the earlier answer helped with that question.

Comment: The update is completely unrelated to the original question, and you did not even say whether the earlier answer helped.   Lmfit has a mailing list: please use that.

Without a traceback and output, and only reading the code, we can only guess at the problem.  In further posts, give a minimal example, the full text output, and the full traceback.

I do not understand what you mean by "36 curve fits".  There is one objective function and one call to minimize(): you are doing one fit.  You loop over xs.shape[1] -- that *must be* the number of data sets, presumably 6. No?

Comment: ^Thanks for the answer. I will post a more detailed question. To answer yes I have only one function to minimize and have 6 datasets (x1,y1,...x6,y6) each one with a texp(texp1,texp2...texp6). Your previous answer put me in the right track for defining the texp and for that I'm very grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a related question and answer that might be useful for review:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242729/chi-squared-of-simultaneous-least-squares-fitted-data/